# Memory data bus decomposition

Tags: memory, switch-statement, dma

Say we have a 32-bit wide memory bus to a shared memory in a network switch. Now I want to make the storing of packets maximize parallel. I put a DMA after each input port, so the switch controller will not be blocked until one packet is stored completely. Assume one packet of each input port is 8 bits. So Could the memory bus be decomposed into 4 8-bit sub-memory buses in order to make each DMA could lead a 8-bit wide packet into the corresponding memory address parallelly(ignore conflicts temporarily)?

Sorry for such a weird question, and for not quite knowing about the computer organization and architecture.